# Encoding in Java Stream API

Tags: java

I started to master the Stream API, as I ran into a problem, java displays the text in Russian incorrectly, it seems to me that there is a problem with the encoding.

Error: ����

Code:

```
package javalearn;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Library {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(cities, 
            "Мосвка", "Лондон", "Мадрид", "Ереван",
            "Баку");
cities.stream()
.filter(s -> s.length() == 4)
.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}

}
```

Comment: I suggest you first try getting rid of the stream part entirely. Just have `String text = "Мосвка"; System.out.println(text);`. I strongly suspect that will have the same problem... which means you can focus on whether it's the input (e.g. the compiler encoding) or the output (the console).

Comment: `String text = "Hello World"; System.out.println(text);` I did this, it seems to me, now it seems to me that the problem is not with the encoding, it seems to me that it redefines it to another data type

Comment: The problem is almost certainly with the configuration of the command line where you're running your program.  There is almost certainly nothing wrong with your program.

Comment: @Maksim1251: I didn't suggest doing that though - I suggested `String text = "Мосвка"`. It's *very* rare for ASCII text like "Hello World" to have encoding problems. (I strongly suspect that if you only use ASCII text in your existing program, that will work fine too...)

Comment: I know this is not a solution to the problem, but I partially solved it, earlier I created a Gradle project and implemented this code in it, now I created a pure Java project without Gradle and the problem has disappeared, I found where to dig, today I’m unlikely to do it, but tomorrow I will definitely look for a solution and publish it here already in the Gradle project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, I don’t know if it’s a good way, go to Run Configurations, select the Cummon section in the project section, set Use system encoding windows-1251 in Encoding, if you put Other UTF-8, the result has not changed, this one is the best, thank you for your attention.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]